# How do i create a triangle div with a border and a background property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a div triangle which has a border and I also can change the background color and also this needs to be draggable.
How do I do it?

I tried  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
and also with before after pseudo element but here is not an actual border which can be a problem ... Anyone can help?:) thanks

Comment: Use a [CSS triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution (without border):
html:

```
<div class="arrow-up" id="arrow-up"></div>
```

css:

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("arrow-up"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

---

Triangle with border:

html:

```
<div class="arrow-up" id="arrow-up">
  <div class="inside-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}

.inside-triangle {
  left: -60px;
  top: 6px;
   width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("arrow-up"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the border?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with skew transformation:

```css
.tri {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
}

.tri::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left:0;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
  background:red;
}
*,*::before {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>
```

Another idea with multiple background where the trick is to stack two triangle shapes:

```css
.tri {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    /*top one*/
    linear-gradient(to top right ,red 49.2%,transparent 50%) calc(100% - 5px) 7px/calc(50.2% - 5px) calc(100% - 2 * 5px),
    linear-gradient(to top left ,red 49.2%,transparent 50%) 5px 7px/calc(50.2% - 5px) calc(100% - 2 * 5px),
    /*bottom one*/
    linear-gradient(to top left ,#000 49.2%,transparent 50%) left/50.2% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top right,#000 49.2%,transparent 50%) right/50.2% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>
```

You can add CSS variables for better control:

```css
.tri {
  --border-color:#000;
  --back-color:red;
  --border:5px;
  
  --c1:var(--back-color) 49.2%,transparent 50%;
  --c2:var(--border-color) 49.2%,transparent 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    /*top one*/
    linear-gradient(to top right, var(--c1)) calc(100% - var(--border)) calc(1.25*var(--border))/calc(50.2% - var(--border)) calc(100% - 2 * var(--border)),
    linear-gradient(to top left ,var(--c1)) var(--border) calc(1.25*var(--border))/calc(50.2% - var(--border)) calc(100% - 2 * var(--border)),
    /*bottom one*/
    linear-gradient(to top left ,var(--c2)) left/50.2% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top right,var(--c2)) right/50.2% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>

<div class="tri" style="--border:10px;--border-color:green;"></div>


<div class="tri" style="--border:15px;--back-color:blue;"></div>
```

Comment: This is closer to my idea but somehow the right edge is sharp a rest is not any idea how to fix that?:)

Comment: @GáborPehl this a side effect of the skew, I have added another way ;) will update with more